# Equality operation to check if four values in an array are equal, the values have to be after one another

Tags: c

This function should return the k at which the first value is equal to the next etc.
The function is currently giving me 0 as the output.

```
int function(double array1[])
{
    int k = 0, count = 0;

    for( k = 0; k < 720; k++ )
    {
        if( ( (array1[k]   != 0) && 
              (array1[k+1] != 0)) && 
            ( (array1[k+2] != 0) && 
              (array1[k+3] != 0) ) )
        {
            if( ( (array1[k]) == 
                  (array1[k+1]) ) == 
                ( (array1[k+2]) ==
                  (array1[k+3]) ) )
            {
                count++ ;
            }
        }
    }

    return count;
}
```

Comment: Do not write such code! never! Your should be careful with operator precedence, andpleaseusewhitespacestoseparatelogicallywhatshouldnotbetogether.

Comment: what would you suggest then?

Comment: @mellow I can suggest to use Python instead of C.:)

Comment: @mellow The function has undefined behavior provided that the array indeed has 720 elements. And it is a bad idea to use magic numbers like 720.

Comment: Clearly define what the function is intended to do.  For example you say it should return an index, but you are returning `count` which is entirely different.  Comparing floating-point values for equality is problematic - the the values in the arrays are calculated in any way, nominally equal values may not be exactly equal in the binary representation.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow it has to be in C :(

Comment: The value of an equality-test operation (operator `==`) is either 1 or 0, depending on whether the operands are, in fact, equal.  Thus, chaining `==` operations as you are doing does not have the effect you hoped it would.

Comment: Floating point values are not comparing very well. What if they are different by 0.0000000001? Is it still considered equal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have flawed and over complicated logic.  To determine that four consecutive values are equal and not equal to zero:

```
    double a = array1[k] ;
    double b = array1[k + 1] ;
    double c = array1[k + 2] ;
    double d = array1[k + 3] ;

    if( a != 0 &&
        a == b &&
        a == c &&
        a == d )
    {
        ...
    }
```

However for testing consecutive equality the following is more efficient and allows easier extension of the consecutive count:

```
double previous = array1[0] ;
for( k = 1, count = 0; count < MIN_CONSECUTIVE && k < ARRAY1_LEN; k++ )
{    
    next = array1[k] ;
    if( next != 0 && previous == next )
    {
        count++ ;
    }
}

return count == MIN_CONSECUTIVE ? k : -1 ;
```

However comparing floating-point values for exact equality is problematic, better:

```
if( fabs(next) < MIN_EQUALITY && 
    fabs(previous - next) < MIN_EQUALITY )
```

or in the first case:

```
    if( fabs(a) < MIN_EQUALITY &&
        fabs(a - b) <  MIN_EQUALITY &&
        fabs(a - c) <  MIN_EQUALITY &&
        fabs(a - d) <  MIN_EQUALITY )
    {
        ...
    }
```

Where `MIN_EQUALITY` is some small value of acceptable error or difference.  For example if say equal to 6 decimal places is sufficient then `MIN_EQUALITY == 0.000001`.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to give your code some structure, this is an example

```
int compare(const int *const array, size_t k, size_t size)
{
    for (int j = k + 1; ((j < k + 4) && (j < size)); ++j) {
        // If a signle value is not equal to
        // `array[k]' we immediately return
        // false. 
        if (array[k] != array[j]) {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;    
}

int function(const int *const array, size_t size)
{
    int count = 0;
    for (int k = 1; k < size; k++) {
        // If array[k - 1] == 0, then it doesn't matter if the following
        // three values are equal to it, so we skip this one
        if (array[k - 1] == 0) {
            continue;
        }

        // Check that all the following three values are equal to
        // `array[k - 1]'
        if (compare(array, k - 1, size) != 0) {
            count += 1;
        }
    }
    // Now this could be the expected value
    return count;
}
```

Also, note some changes I've made

1. I changed `double` to `int`, because if anything it doesn't make sense to compare `double` values for equality because of floating point precision.
2. I now, check if all 3 values following the value of interest are equal in a different function, that makes the code clear and anyone who reads it understands what it's doing.
3. I changed `int array[]` to `int *array` because if anything `int array[]` is simply confusing if you are not a [c](/questions/tagged/c) expert, and if you are you know that no matter the syntax, `array` is a pointer.
4. Added 2 `const` qualifiers,

   1. The first one, because we can ensure that these functions wont modify the array and you should.
   2. The second one, because we don't want to accidentally reassing the pointer inside the function, nor accidentally increment it or alter it.
5. Added the array size as a parameter so that the function is reusable, a very important feature of functions.
6. Added comments to explain what the code does. Note that the purpose of these comments is not only to "*eplxain what the code does*" because that's clear from the code itself, it's precisely because this way you can see if there is consistency between what you thought the code would do and what it *actually* does.

And if you want a slightly nicer version, this one would work too

```
int compare(const int *const array, size_t size, size_t width)
{
    for (const int *next = array + 1; next < array + width; ++next) {
        // If a signle value is not equal to
        // `array[0]' we immediately return
        // false. 
        if (array[0] != next[0]) {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;    
}

int function(const int *const array, size_t size, size_t width)
{
    int count = 0;
    for (int k = 1; k < size; k++) {
        // If array[k - 1] == 0, then it doesn't matter if the 
        // following three values are equal to it, so we skip this
        // one
        if (array[k - 1] == 0) {
            continue;
        }    
        // Check that all the following three values are equal to
        // `array[k - 1]'
        if (compare(&array[k - 1], size, width) != 0) {
            count += 1;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

It doesn't improve much over the previous one, but it makes one more parameter adjustable, so the function is more generic and hence, it's more "*reusable*".

Answer (score 0):

> Equality operation to check if four values in an array are equal

OP's code finds the equality of array[k] to the next one.  Then  finds the equality of array[k+2] and its next one.  Lastly these two equalities, both with a 0 or 1 value, are compared.  [@John Bollinger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46573257/equality-operation-to-check-if-four-values-in-an-array-are-equal-the-values-hav/46573424#comment80100475_46573257)

```
1,1,1,1 is true
1,1,2,2 is true
1,2,3,4 is true
```

This is not "check if four values in an array are equal".

---

Check if the 1st equals the 2nd, and if so, then if the 1st equals the 3rd, etc.  Avoid naked magic numbers.  `O(size + n)`

```
#define ARRAY_N 720
#define MATCH_N 4

int function(double array1[]){
  int k=0, count = 0;

  for(k=0; k<ARRAY_N-(MATCH_N-1); k++){
    double base = array1[k];
    int i;
    for (i = 1; i < MATCH_N; i++) {
      if (base != array1[k+i])) {
        break;
      }
    }
    if (i == MATCH_N) count++;
  }
  return count;
}
```

---

Better to pass in the array size and match length too.

```
unsigned consecutive_match(const double array1[], size_t size, size_t n){
  unsigned count = 0;
  if (size >= n) {
    ...
```

---

A more advanced version would take advantage of consecutive matches.  `O(size)`

```
size_t consecutive_match(const double array1[], size_t size, size_t n) {
  // Pathological cases
  if (n <= 1 || size == 0) {
    if (n > 0) return size;
    return 0;
  }

  size_t count = 0;
  size_t match_length = 1;
  for (size_t k = 1; k < size; k++) {
    if (array1[k - 1] == array1[k]) {
      match_length++;
      if (match_length == n) {
        match_length--;
        count++;
      }
    } else {
      match_length = 1;
    }
  }
  return count;
}
```